# Nextjs 13 app directory layout loading order

Tags: typescript, next.js

I have the following components:

**/app/layout.tsx**

`console.log('layout1')`

**/app/chat/layout.tsx**

`console.log('layout2')`

When I navigate to /app/chat, the order I see in my console is:

```
layout2
layout1
```

I imagined that the root layout (`/app/layout`) would load before the child layout (`/app/chat/layout`), but this does not appear to be the case in Next 13.5.4. Is this loading flow expected, or is this a bug?